# iPhone WKWebView: loadData does not work with types (Excel, MSWord, PPT, RTF) it shows all ascii characters

Tags: swift, uiwebview, webkit, wkwebview

I am trying without saving the file in disk, reading them through Data, it works with pdf perfectly but with docx file, it shows ascii characters.

I don't know, where am I doing wrong.

What I tried:

```
 let data = filesData
    
    let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x:20,y:120,width:view.frame.size.width-40, height:view.frame.size.height-40))
    
    
    webView.load(data, mimeType: "application/msword", characterEncodingName:"UTF8", baseURL: (fileURL)!)
    view.addSubview(webView)
```

[image]

Comment: The title says that you are using UIWebView when in fact you are using WKWebView.  And why are you trying to open a propriety file type (except RTF) with a web view control?

Comment: Hi El tomato, I did a mistake writing the right  title thanks,  I didn’t understand what u r trying to write, can u be little bit more clear plz.

Comment: Earlier, you said that you wanted to open MS PowerPoint file type and others.  Are you able to open a PowerPoint file and an Excel file with Safari, Firefox and other web browsers?

Comment: Using Swift language or Objective -c you can open the Excel, docx and etc... file with WKWebView. if I save the file in disk I can see the file with webView. for security reason I  don't want to save it... probably it should be a bug from apple that doesn't show Docx file, since others have the same problem.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance...  Have you read the following topic?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57775495/loading-microsoft-office-documents-in-wkwebview

Comment: Yes, but didn't resolve my issue...

Comment: Thanks El Tomato. I tried work around to resolve my issue. anyway thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

My objc version of the swift code at: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/109589. Note that self.mainWebView is a WKWebview. This can be extended for other troublesome formats as well.

```
    NSString *word = @"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
    
    if ([objEmailActivity.contentType isEqualToString:word]) {
        
        // WKWebview has a bug where it won't render docx files correctly
        // This is a workaround suggested at https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/109589
        
        NSString *docStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;base64,%@", [dat base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0] ];
        
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:docStr];
        
        NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        
        [self.mainWebView loadRequest:req];

         
    }
```

Comment: works, but too slow for files about 5-6 MB (10-15 seconds to render)